# Sending square wave over PCB track

Tags: impedance-matching

How is it possible to send a high frequency square wave over PCB track when it is not possible to match the impedance of the track to all the frequency components?!
Usually we match only the main frequency of the wave, but harmonics are important part of the square wave.

Thank you!

Comment: A transmission line has the same characteristic impedance at "all" frequencies

Comment: An ideal 50 Ohm transmission line that is either infinite in length or is terminated with a resistance of 50 Ohms on the far end will allow any signal to be transmitted with no distortion. A PCB trace is not always an ideal transmission line. But it is not clear if you want to have a discussion about the non-idealities or if you are under the mistaken impression that frequency specific matching is used in PCB transmission lines for square waves. If you can focus your question better, maybe a good answer can be written.

Comment: Ok! I think 50 ohm resistor termination answers my question. Resistor is a broadband component. Thank you!

Comment: Ideal resistors have infinite BW. Small SMT resistors are good up to a few GHz if not beyond.

Comment: @Tobalt. No, a transmission line does not have the same characteristic impedance at all frequencies. However, there is a wide _band_ of frequencies where it has a fairly constant characteristic impedance.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy therefore the **"**  I wanted to express that it is not literal

Comment: @tobalt ahh. OK.

Answer (score 3):

> How is it possible to send a high frequency square wave over PCB track

we do it all the time

> ... when it is not possible to match the impedance of the track to all the frequency components?!...

who says?

> Usually we match only the main frequency of the wave, but harmonics are important part of the square wave.

When we match a logic transmission line on a board, it's matched at all frequencies, not just one. Harmonics are of course important for reproduction of the square wave.

Now there are a number of caveats to add to that broad assertion.

'Matching' means subtly different things to logic, and to RF. Not the concept of matching *per se*, but the assumptions we make about where we are starting from, and where we want to get to, and what components we are going to use.

With a logic trace on a board, we set the bar rather low, and the assumption is that we want to avoid multiple edges being seen at any of the receivers. To this end we generally assume the track itself has a constant impedance, the logic buffers are low resistance output, high impedance input, and they must be matched in at one or both ends by adding resistors. These are all broad band components and so the line ends up with a broad match.

With RF components, we want to do things like maximise power transfer, where the components themselves have potentially narrowband reactive port matches (especially antennae). This often needs narrowband components like Ls, Cs, and short lengths of transmission line of different impedances, which of course ends up with a narrowband match.

Having said all that, typically tracks on a logic board are microstrip, and these have *dispersion*, where different frequencies travel at different speeds. The same goes for any mixed dielectric environment like twisted pair. A square wave's harmonics will arrive at different times at the end of a long dispersive line, and this is a *Bad Thing*.

For very high speed work over very long lines, we usually need to take active measures to pre-emphasise the driver, and equalise the receiver, to sharpen up the transitions. This is known as 'opening the eye', which you'll understand if you've ever seen an 'eye diagram' of how a logic signal is received over such a line.